# If $ x+iy = \sqrt{\frac{a+ib}{c+id} } ,$Show that$ (x^2+y^2)^2 = \frac {a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2} $

Tags: complex-numbers

$ x+iy = \sqrt{\frac{a+ib}{c+id} } , $Show that $ ({x^2+y^2})^2 = \frac {a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2} $

How do i do this ?I tried squaring both sides but x+iy expansion becomes difficult when squaring the next time .I also tried conjugating the R.H.S

Comment: Hint: For $z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|^2 = |z^2|$.

Comment: where do i use the mod ?

Comment: $\left|x^2+y^2 \right|^2=\left|x+iy \right|^4=\left|\sqrt{\dfrac{a+ib}{c+id} } \right|^4=\left|\dfrac{a+ib}{c+id}  \right|^2=\dfrac {a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2=|x+iy|^2=\left|\sqrt{\frac{a+ib}{c+id}}\right|^2=\left|\frac{a+ib}{c+id}\right|$$

Therefore,

$$(x^2+y^2)^2=\frac{|a+ib|^2}{|c+id|^2}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

> Notice, when $q\space\wedge\space s\space\wedge\space z\in\mathbb{C}$, so we set $q=x+yi,s=a+bi,z=c+di$:
>
> - $$\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2=\left(\Re^2[q]+\Im^2[q]\right)^2=|q|^4$$
> - $$a^2+b^2=\Re^2[s]+\Im^2[s]=|s|^2$$
> - $$c^2+d^2=\Re^2[z]+\Im^2[z]=|z|^2$$

So:

$$x+yi=\sqrt{\frac{a+bi}{c+di}}\Longleftrightarrow q=\sqrt{\frac{s}{z}}$$

Now, we can find the absolute value:

$$\left|q\right|=\left|\sqrt{\frac{s}{z}}\right|\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|q\right|=\left|\left(\frac{s}{z}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right|\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|q\right|=\left|\frac{s}{z}\right|^{\frac{1}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|q\right|=\left(\frac{\left|s\right|}{\left|z\right|}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|q\right|^4=\left(\frac{\left|s\right|}{\left|z\right|}\right)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|q\right|^4=\frac{\left|s\right|^2}{\left|z\right|^2}$$